# NeighboringCellInfo: почему не получаем список каждый раз?

Tags: android, java

Код

```
TextView test;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    List<NeighboringCellInfo>  neighCell = null;
    TelephonyManager telManager = ( TelephonyManager )getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    neighCell = telManager.getNeighboringCellInfo();
    Log.d("Test",Integer.toString(neighCell.size()));
    test.setText("Кол-во соседних вышек: " + Integer.toString(neighCell.size()));
    for (int i = 0; i < neighCell.size(); i++) {
        try
        {
            Log.d("Test",Integer.toString(neighCell.size()));
            NeighboringCellInfo thisCell = neighCell.get(i);
            int thisNeighCID = thisCell.getCid();
            int thisNeighRSSI = thisCell.getRssi();
            int thisNeighLac = thisCell.getLac();
            String dBm = String.valueOf(-113 + 2 * thisNeighRSSI) + " dBm";
            Log.d("Test"," "+thisNeighCID+" - "+dBm + "-" + thisNeighLac);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            NeighboringCellInfo thisCell = neighCell.get(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что он не при каждом запуске получает вышки. После нескольких перезапусков срабатывает показывает от 1 до 4 вышек со всеми корректными данными (в дебагер вывожу). Так в чем проблема, почему не получаем список каждый раз?

Comment: Поправьте разметку кода, а то глаза сломать можно :(

Comment: спс модерам.уже поправили

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ситуация с этим getNeighboringCellInfo запутанная. В интернетах люди пишут, что у кого-то работает только в режиме 2G и не работает в 3G, у кого-то работает и в 2G и в 3G, но только не на Самсунгах...

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536705/getneighboringcellinfo-returning-null-list), чтобы не быть голословным.

Видимо наблюдаем злополучную фрагментацию устройств в действии...

Comment: ну а допустим программно мы не можем перейти на 2G?

Comment: Я такого способа не знаю :(